# If $(i^n a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges and $a_n\in\mathbb{R}$ then $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to 0

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Is it true that if $(i^n a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges and $a_n\in\mathbb{R}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $0$? To me it seems that way, but I don't know how to show it.

I got that $a_n^4$ converges to $(lim_{n\to\infty} a_n)^4$, but I don't think that helps.

Comment: What's the value of $i$?

Comment: i is the imaginary unit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is true because if $b_n:=\mathrm i^na_n\to b$ then $b$ is both a real number (as the limit of the real subsequence $(b_{2k}=(-1)^ka_{2k})$) and an imaginary number (as the limit of the imaginary subsequence $(b_{2k+1}=(-1)^k\,\mathrm i\,a_{2k+1})$), hence $b=0,$ so $a_n=\mathrm i^{-n}b_n$ converges to $0,$ as the product of the bounded sequence $(\mathrm i^{-n})$ by the null sequence $(b_n).$

Answer (score 2):

$i^{n}a_n-i^{n+1}a_{n+1} \to 0$, so $|i^{n}a_n-i^{n+1}a_{n+1}|=|a_n-ia_{n+1}| \to 0$ and so $a_n^{2}+a_{n+1}^{2} \to 0$. Hence,  $a_n \to 0$.